# Align plotly plots in R-Markdown

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

Can someone tell me if there is a way to align plotly plots in R-Markdown?. More specifically: Currently my plots are being placed one after another. I would like to have a grid-like format. I achieved this before, using the simple plot function, but that doesn't seem to work with plotly.

The following is an example of my prior code, that worked with the simple plot function. Can I make that work, assuming I were using plotly?

Thanks in advance.

```
{r comment = NA,fig.width=14, fig.height=14}
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 4, 2, byrow = TRUE))

m_alt <- miete[miete$baujahr <= 22,]
m_neu <- miete[miete$baujahr > 22,]

plot(table(m_alt$bezirk),main="",ylab="Frequency",xlab="Bezirk")
plot(table(m_neu$bezirk),main="",ylab="Frequency",xlab="Bezirk")

plot(table(m_alt$wohnflaeche),main="",ylab="Frequency",xlab="Wohnfläche")
plot(table(m_neu$wohnflaeche),main="",ylab="Frequency",xlab="Wohnfläche")

plot(table(m_alt$wohnlage,m_alt$zimmerzahl),main="Altbau: Wohnlage u. Zimmerzahl")
plot(table(m_neu$wohnlage,m_neu$zimmerzahl),main="Neubau: Wohnlage u. Zimmerzahl")

plot(table(miete$bezirk,miete$zimmerzahl),main="Bezirk u. Zimmerzahl")
plot(table(miete$warmwasser,miete$bezirk),main="Warmwasser u. Bezirk")
```

Comment: Please do create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: None of the code in your question uses `plotly`. Is that intentional? All of your code is using Base R.  Your output from RMarkdown has a lot to do with how best to achieve the desired outcome. You really should edit your answer and in addition to making it reproducible as @January wrote, make sure to include your YAML.

Comment: @kat: I think they wanted to demonstrate how they would like the output of plotly to be.